# Is there a way to boost performance in this query

Tags: php, mysql, performance

I'm trying to find duplicates in my table using this query:

```
SELECT  COUNT(*) as cnt, GROUP_CONCAT(id) AS ids
    FROM  `table`
    GROUP BY  col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6, col7, col8, col9, col10
    HAVING  cnt > 1';
```

It works well, but it's a little bit to slow. Do you have any ideas how to speed it up?

Comment: The group by is likely what's killing the performance, dump out what happens when you describe it `DESCRIBE SELECT COUNT(*) as cnt, GROUP_CONCAT(id) AS ids FROM table GROUP BY col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6, col7, col8, col9, col10 HAVING cnt > 1');` that will provide a better idea of what's happening with the query.

Comment: This feels a lot like a "Code Review" type question.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/nxX9Veh.png this  is result of that describe. Table has about 600k rows, better performance is when I'm dividing query by taking 50k rows one time in loop.

Comment: You've given us very little information to go on. Please read this, especially the part about query performance.  http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/  Then please [edit] your question.

Comment: Do you want to just _find_ the duplicates?  Or do you want to _remove_ the duplicates?  What percentage of the table is dups?  For a small percentage, one technique works better than another.

Answer (score 0):

You're asking MySQL to do a surprising complex grouping task.

Try creating a covering index mentioning all the columns in your `GROUP BY` clause, then the `id` column. That may help MySQL carry out your query efficiently.

Notice this, though: if you've simplified the query by leaving out some `WHERE` clauses, you'll need an index that takes them into account.

http://use-the-index-luke.com/ is a good reference.